# how does returning a static variable make a difference?

Tags: c

```
int main(){    
  char *s ;
  char *fun( ) ;
  s = fun( ) ;
  printf ( "%s", s ) ;
}

char *fun( ){    
  char buffer[30] ;
  strcpy ( buffer, "RAM - Rarely Adequate Memory") ;
  return ( buffer ) ;
}
```

why does the above code print unpredictable results? how does making char buffer[30] static help?

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Comment: @RohitJain That's the all new syntax of Java 11.

Comment: @zavg It's a function declaration that's only visible within the scope of main.

Comment: It is probably getting late which is why I'm seeing spaces at places where I shouldn't be seeing them, and not seeing them at places where they should be.

Answer (score 5):

A `static` variable exists for the entire run-time of your program, unlike a normal "automatic" variable that only exists as long as its parent scope exists.

If you do return a pointer to a non-`static` variable, that means the caller gets a reference to memory that, when the called function has returned, no longer holds what it did inside the function. That memory cannot validly be accessed by the caller, and doing so will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: That is what a static variable is but why is it unpredictable behavior?

Comment: You should precise why it's unpredictable (i.e. The memory can be used elsewhere)

Answer (score 2):

An automatic variable resides on the (function-call) stack. Thus, when the next function is called, (`printf` in this example), the stack contents get over written. Hence the unpredictable errors.

Whereas, static variables get stored in data segment. (Very similar to global variables, as far as storage is considered.)

Hence static variables are not overwritten during the next function call. Hence it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[30];
```

That line allocates the space for buffer on the stack.  The storage goes away when the function exits and will be overwritten by the automatic variables declared in printf.

```
static char buffer[30];
```

causes the buffer to be allocated from the data segment of the program, so it won't get overwritten when you call printf.  However, as it only gets allocated once, each call to `fun` overwrites the previous value (not a problem for you because you are strcpy'ing a constant string into it.

Answer (score 0):

In the code

```
char *fun( ){    
  char buffer[30] ;
  strcpy ( buffer, "RAM - Rarely Adequate Memory") ;
  return ( buffer ) ;
}
```

the `buffer` array only exists for the lifetime of the function itself; once the function exits, the memory that was used by `buffer` is made available for other threads or processes to use.  This means that in the time between the execution of the statements

```
s = fun( ) ;
printf ( "%s", s ) ;
```

another thread or process could have overwritten the memory that `buffer` was using.

If you declare `buffer` as `static`, such as

```
char *fun( ){    
  static char buffer[30] ;
  strcpy ( buffer, "RAM - Rarely Adequate Memory") ;
  return ( buffer ) ;
}
```

then the memory used by `buffer` is allocated at program startup and held until the program terminates, meaning nothing else can overwrite it.  This comes at a cost, however; `fun` is no longer [re-entrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29).  As the function is currently written, it's not a problem, since it returns the same value for any invocation.  However, if `fun` were meant to return a different string for different circumstances, you could run into problems if one call is interrupted by another call.

A third option is to allocate the memory for `buffer` dynamically:

```
char *fun( ){    
  char *buffer = malloc( sizeof *buffer * 30 ) ;
  if ( buffer )
    strcpy ( buffer, "RAM - Rarely Adequate Memory") ;
  return ( buffer ) ;
}
```

This solves the first two problems; the contents of the buffer are preserved after the function exits, and you're not limited to a single, static buffer.  But since there's no such thing as a free lunch, now the calling function has to make sure to release that memory when it's finished with it:

```
int main(){    
  char *s ;
  char *fun( ) ;
  s = fun( ) ;
  printf ( "%s", s ) ;
  free( s );
}
```